# iOS HTML Web App (PhoneGap) over scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, cordova

This problem has been addressed several times on Stack Overflow, but not entirely.

The problem is that iOS allows you to "over-scroll" a webpage which looks terrible for the header and footer of a web app. A simple work-around is to prevent the browser from doing anything with 'touchmove'.

This is the simple hack (in Coffeescript):

```
$('body').on 'touchmove', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
```

Now, if you have content in-between your header and footer that needs to be scrolled, this is an issue, so you can have some simple logic to work around this:

```
$('body').on 'touchmove', (e) ->
  if not $('.content').has($(e.target)).length
    e.preventDefault()
```

A side note (just in case it happens to be relevant), a nice little trick to get momentum scrolling is this pit of CSS:

```
.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The problem now is that if the current scroll position is at the top and I scroll up (pulling down), I overscroll and it pulls down the header. Same happens the other way. If the content view is scrolled to the bottom and I try to scroll further, the footer is pulled up and overscrolled. Now just to be clear, by scroll, I mean touch scrolling in the iPhone or iOS Simulator.

So the question is how do I prevent this overscrolling?

Its simple in pseudocode:

```
if at the top and scrolling up or at the bottom and scrolling down
  e.preventDefault
```

I'm having all kinds of trouble with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this in the cordova config.xml

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

When you put the above line in your config and create the build the overscroll feature is disabled! So no need for JavaScript to fix this.. phew!